# Clojure best practice for nested let

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is is good practice to use Clojure nested `let` in the following way, or is it confusing ?

```
(defn a-fun [config]
  (let [config (-> config (parse) (supply-defaults))]
  ;; do something with config
  ))
```

I noticed I have this pattern of parsing/checking/validating things quite often in my input functions that talk to the external world (in this case a Clojurescript library that exposes public functions, but I also had Compojure routes with this same feeling).

Is it confusing, because one has to understand the rules for bindings visibility (not sure what the exact wording is) ?

What would be the idiomatic way to do it ? Change the `config` name to `parsed-config`, put it in another function, something else completely ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would reach for this idiom when

- the rebinding is the same kind of thing and
- you want to make clear that the local binding supersedes the
  global one.

For example

```
(defn fact [n]
  (loop [n n, answer 1]
    (if (pos? n)
      (recur (dec n) (* answer n))
      answer)))
```

This also stops you using the global binding by accident, as I was prone to do.

Answer (score 3):

@Thumbnail's answer is good, but I personally would almost never shadow an outer binding with an inner one in this way.  Even if you understand binding rules, and want to shadow an outer variable for a good reason, it's confusing for someone reading the code--which could very well be you, later, after you've forgotten how the code works.

Suppose I have a complex function, and I see the variable `foo` used somewhere in the middle of it.  I look up and see a binding for it--perhaps as a function parameter, which would be obvious and easy to notice.  If I don't notice that somewhere below that, the name was rebound, then I will misunderstand what's in the variable.

So I usually make up new, related names that correspond to the role of the different variables in the code.  Sometimes the name differences are somewhat arbitrary.

I think these are good reasons not to shadow variables, and I think @Thumbnail gives go reasons to go ahead and shadow them.  There are tradeoffs, and you have to decide what's best for your situation.

Short functions are probably better contexts for shadowing.  Personally, I'd add a very noticeable comment if I did this sort of thing, or if I was doing it over and over again, maybe a very noticeable comment near the top of the file.

EDIT: As nha's comment made me realize, it can be more reasonable to shadow variables when the new binding occurs immediately after the previous binding; that makes it hard to miss the fact that the name is being redefined.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Would it be ok then in your opinion if this sort of things was always at the top of the function (like in my example) ?

Comment: Yes, that seems completely reasonable, now that you mention it.  My own explanation of my practice provides a rationale for it!

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to slightly rename the argument, keeping the general name for the "final" version of the data:

```
(defn a-fun [config-in]
  (let [config (-> config-in (parse) (supply-defaults))]
  ;; do something with config
  ))
```

I also sometimes use the suffixes `-arg`, `-orig`, etc to differentiate various stages of processing.

Comment: That's obviously an option, I'd be interested into what advantages/disadvantages you found while using that convention ?

Comment: The idea is that the "unusual" version gets the suffix, which makes it longer and a bit harder to type.  Typically, `config-in` (or `config-raw` or...) is only used once, then immediately cleaned up and saved as `config` which is the "normal" version and may be used many times.